# Proxying Google Street View JS API via local url

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

We have an intranet application and we want to use Google Street View API.
Also we plan to buy premium access, but before we need to check this.
User computers do not have direct access to internet.
We use ManagedFusion.Rewriter to proxy queries through local url to external services.
Is there a way to use Street View JS API via such proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a nodejs (or equivalent) service that will a simple proxy

We are using the same in one of the app so we can control the parameters along with local storage.

Hope this helps

Comment: We are using proxy based on ManagedFusion.Rewriter library. But we can't redirect api queries to our local proxy.
For example, we can access maps api via local url http://server.local/proxy/maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=apikey. But other queries will be on external urls https://maps.googleapis.com/ and etc. We need to rewrite this to local urls.